# Compile standalone TikZ picture as <presentation> or <article> via beamerarticle

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, standalone, beamerarticle

I use Beamer-style overlays (`\uncover`, `\only`, etc.) in TikZ pictures that I embed into two different documents generated via `\usepackage{beamerarticle}`:

- A Beamer `<presentation>` that translates the overlays to piecewise uncovered content.
- An `<article>` document in which the overlays are ignored (which is actually convenient because I provide this as a post-presentation handout, in which all information *should* be visible at once).

#### Minimal working example for `<presentation>`

To conveniently preview my TikZ pictures without having to compile the documents they are embedded into, I rely on the `standalone` class, which supports Beamer overlays via `\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}` and `\begin{standaloneframe}`. This mechanism allows me to preview a TikZ picture as it will appear in my Beamer `<presentation>`, as the following MWE illustrates.

```
\documentclass[tikz, beamer]{standalone}%

\begin{document}%

\begin{standaloneframe}{Standalone frame title}%

\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node at (0,0) {This text is shown on all frames.};%
  \uncover<2->{%
    \node at (0,-1) {This text is shown on the second frame.};%
  }%
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{standaloneframe}%

\end{document}%
```

#### Minimal working example for `<article>`

In addition, I also need to be able to preview the TikZ picture as it will appear in my `<article>` document (ie, without overlays and with the  class's default sans serif fonts). This can be achieved by

1. Removing the `[beamer]` option from the `standalone` class
2. loading `\usepackage{beamerarticle}`, and
3. removing or commenting `\begin{standaloneframe}` and `\end{standaloneframe}`,

as the following MWE illustrates.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}% EDIT 1: Remove [beamer] option

\usepackage{beamerarticle}% EDIT 2: Load beamerarticle package

\begin{document}%

%\begin{standaloneframe}{Standalone frame title}% EDIT 3: Comment standalone frame

\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node at (0,0) {This text is shown on all frames.};%
  \uncover<2->{%
    \node at (0,-1) {This text is shown on the second frame.};%
  }%
\end{tikzpicture}

%\end{standaloneframe}% EDIT 3: Comment standalone frame

\end{document}%
```

#### How can I simplify switching from `<presentation>` to `<article>`?

*I am looking for a more convenient solution to "flip the switch" between previewing my TikZ pictures in either`<presentation>` or `<article>` mode.*

(Un)commenting one line of code for this purpose would be acceptable, whereas the above solution requires too many edits. My concern for automating this process as much as possible is motivated by the large number of TikZ pictures I need to manage for both scenarios.

Note that this would be a useful feature independently of Beamer-style overlays, since one key advantage of TikZ graphics is that they can be used in the context of different host documents (and thus font environments).

Answer (score 1):

When I have a beamer presentation with many frames with tikzpictures in it, I put each frame in a separate folder and comment all the frames except that I am working with.
For example the code `main.tex` of the presentation is:

```
% !TeX root = main.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
%\input{FramesFolder/frame1}
%\input{FramesFolder/frame2}
\input{FramesFolder/frame3}
\end{document}
```

and the file of the `frame3.tex` in the `FramesFolder` could be:

```
% !TeX root = ../main.tex
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My Picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node at (0,0) {This text is shown on all frames.};%
  \uncover<2->{%
    \node at (0,-1) {This text is shown on the second frame.};%
  }%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

In this way the compilation is very fast. Only at the end I compile all the frames together.
With the "special comments" `% !TeX root =...` in both files when you compile `frame3.tex` all the presentation will compile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am intrigued, but I am not entirely sure in how far the answer addresses the specific situation at hand, which requires both the `standalone` package and Beamer's article mode - your proposed solution does not seem to rely on either?